# How to show fragments in viewpager when back from another fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-viewpager

I  have a fragment within a few fragments are viewPager which includes a listiview each show. Click on any of the items listview when we go to the next fragment, but when the next fragment back button does not display anything in my viewpager

```
public class HomePage extends Fragment {

private View view;
private HomeTabsAdapter mAdapter;
private ViewPager mPagerHome;
public PagerSlidingTabStrip mTabs;
private Typeface typeface;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,  ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.homepage_fragment, container, false);

    mTabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) view.findViewById(R.id.TabsHome);
    mPagerHome = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pagerHome);

    ArrayList<String> title = new ArrayList<>();
    title.add("خبر داغ");
    title.add("اقتصادی");
    title.add("بین المللی");


    mAdapter = new HomeTabsAdapter(HomePage.this.getFragmentManager(), title);
    mPagerHome.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mPagerHome.setCurrentItem(title.size());
    mTabs.setViewPager(mPagerHome);


     typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),"fonts/IRAN-Sans.ttf");


    //jologiri az 3 noghte kardane esme tab ha va font
    LinearLayout tabsContainer = (LinearLayout) mTabs.getChildAt(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < tabsContainer.getChildCount(); i++) {
        TextView tab = (TextView) tabsContainer.getChildAt(i);
        tab.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f));
        tab.setPadding(8, 0, 8, 0);
        tab.setTypeface(typeface);
    }

    return view;
}
```

and my view pager adapter

```
public class HomeTabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {


public ArrayList<String> mTitle;

public HomeTabsAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<String> mTitle) {

    super(fm);
    this.mTitle = mTitle;
}


@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position){
        case 0:
            return HotNews.newInstance();
        case 1:
            return  Economic.newInstance();
        case 2:
            return International.newInstance();

    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mTitle.size();
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return mTitle.get(position);
}}
```

and one of fragment

```
public class International extends Fragment {

private View view;
private ItemNews itemNews;
private NewsAdapter adapter;
private FloatingActionButton btn;
private ExpandableListView list;
private static final int SCROLL_TO_TOP = -1;
private static final int SCROLL_TO_BOTTOM = 1;
private static final int SCROLL_DIRECTION_CHANGE_THRESHOLD = 5;
private int mScrollDirection = 0;
private ItemChild childItem;
private ArrayList<ItemChild> child;

public static International newInstance(){
    International international = new International();
    return international;
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,  ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listnews_fragment, container, false);
    list = (ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.ListNews);
    list.setGroupIndicator(null);


    String text = " مسی به همراه بارسلونا ۶ بار قهرمان لالیگا، دو بار قهرمان جام حذفی اسپانیا، پنج بار برنده سوپرکاپ اسپانیا، سه بار قهرمان لیگ قهرمانان اروپا، دو بار\n" +
            " قهرمان سوپر کاپ اروپا و دو بار قهرمان جام باشگاه‌های جهان شده است. مسی اولین و تنها بازیکنی است که در چهار رقابت لیگ قهرمانان اروپا به عنوان آ";

    child = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i <2; i++) {
        childItem = new ItemChild();
        childItem.setId(i);
        childItem.setImageChild("http://bit.do/logo00");
        childItem.setTitleChild("ورزش سه -");
        childItem.setDate("8ساعت قبل");
        child.add(childItem);

    }


    List<ItemNews> news = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        itemNews = new ItemNews();
        itemNews.setId(i);
        itemNews.setmIconSource("http://bit.do/logo00");
        itemNews.setmImage("http://bit.do/image00");
        itemNews.setmSource("ورزش سه -");
        itemNews.setmTime("8ساعت قبل");
        itemNews.setmTitle("messi");
        itemNews.setmNews(text);
        itemNews.setChild(child);
        news.add(itemNews);

    }


    adapter = new NewsAdapter(International.this, news,getActivity());
    list.setAdapter(adapter);


    btn = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.Floating);


    list.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

        int mScrollPosition;

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

            View topChild = view.getChildAt(0);

            int newScrollPosition = 0;
            if (topChild == null) {
                newScrollPosition = 0;
            } else {
                newScrollPosition = -topChild.getTop() + view.getFirstVisiblePosition() * topChild.getHeight();
            }

            if (Math.abs(newScrollPosition - mScrollPosition) >= SCROLL_DIRECTION_CHANGE_THRESHOLD) {
                onScrollPositionChanged(mScrollPosition, newScrollPosition);
            }

            mScrollPosition = newScrollPosition;
        }
    });


    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing `onBackPressed()` in your `FragmentActivity` class 
with the pager `getCurrentItem()`.....it will work surely :)

Comment: my pager in fragment.v4 and fragment in activity and don't use fragment activity